# Transform rotate duplicate element before rotating on IOS

Tags: css, safari

I have menu hamburger icon, which have transform:rotate after click event.
It works good on Chrome, but in Safari I find a bug. It renders a copy of an element, and then rotate this copy. After animation ends everything looks ok, bug visible during the animation.

How can I fix it?

[image]

```js
  $("#burger-menu-icon").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
  });
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.burger-menu {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.burger-menu__dash,
.burger-menu__dash::after,
.burger-menu__dash::before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.burger-menu__dash::after,
.burger-menu__dash::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}

.burger-menu__dash::after {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.burger-menu__dash::before {
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.burger-menu.open .burger-menu__dash {
  transform: translateX(-30px);
  background: transparent;
}

.burger-menu.open .burger-menu__dash::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(20px, -20px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(20px, -20px);
}

.burger-menu.open .burger-menu__dash::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(20px, 20px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(20px, 20px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="burger-menu" id="burger-menu-icon">
    <div class="burger-menu__dash"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have run your snippet on Safari (IOS 15) and there doesn't seem to be any problem (I ran it at a slower speed too so could see  more easily what was going on). What system/version are you using?

Comment: I tested this on IOS 15.1 and the latest version of Safari. Here is [snippet](https://codepen.io/re1mond/pen/ZEXbqvJ) in which i reproduce the bug like on image in post

Comment: OK, so I see the problem when I run your codepen but not when I run your SO snippet. I guess we need to look for what is the difference in the environments. Do you see the problem when you run your SO snippet rather than your codepen one?